# GWT-AI Integration

Tags: java, gwt, applet

I am developing a demo application with using `GwtAI` (Gwt Applet Integration). I have included all the `GwtAI-client.jar,GwtAI-core.jar`.I am referring to the http://code.google.com/p/gwtai/wiki/GettingStarted Following is the code.

**FileUploadingApplet.class**

```
@ImplementingClass(com.nextenders.appletImpl.FileUploadingAppletImpl.class)
@Height("60")
@Width("350")
@Archive("GwtAI-Client.jar,FileUploadingAppletImpl.jar")
@Codebase("applet")
public interface FileUploadingApplet extends Applet{

     public void increment();

     public void decrement();

     public Object getCurrentValue();

}
```

**FileUploadingAppletImpl.class**

```
public class FileUploadingAppletImpl extends JApplet implements FileUploadingApplet {
    JTextField m_fileNameTF = new JTextField(15);
    String controlTransactionId = "";
    JFileChooser m_fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    FileWriter fstream = null;
    long fileLength = 0l;

    @Override
    public void init() { 

        JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();

        m_fileNameTF = new JTextField(20);
        m_fileNameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        m_fileNameTF.setText("0");
        m_fileNameTF.setEditable(false);

        panelMain.add(new JLabel("Current count : "));
        panelMain.add(m_fileNameTF);

        panelMain.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("CounterApplet"));
        panelMain.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        getContentPane().add(panelMain);

    }

     public void increment() {
         int currentCount = Integer.parseInt(m_fileNameTF.getText());
         currentCount++;

         m_fileNameTF.setText(currentCount + "");
 }

 public void decrement() {
         int currentCount = Integer.parseInt(m_fileNameTF.getText());
         currentCount--;

         m_fileNameTF.setText(currentCount + "");
 }

 public Object getCurrentValue() {
         return m_fileNameTF.getText();
 }
}
```

**NTFileUpload.java**

```
private void createPanel(){
        PopupPanel panel = new PopupPanel();
        panel.setPopupPosition(500, 500);
        panel.setHeight("600px");
        panel.setHeight("900px");

        final FileUploadingApplet fileUploadApplet = (FileUploadingApplet) GWT.create(FileUploadingApplet.class);
        VerticalPanel panelMain = new VerticalPanel();
        Button buttonInc = new Button("Increment");
        buttonInc.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
          public void onClick(Widget sender) {
              fileUploadApplet.increment();
          }
        });
        Widget widgetApplet = AppletJSUtil.createAppletWidget(fileUploadApplet);
        panelMain.add(widgetApplet);
        panelMain.add(buttonInc);
        panel.add(panelMain);
        panel.show();
    }
```

I have followed the package structure as per the link. But I am getting following Exception.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.gwtai.applet.generator.AppletProxyGenerator.generate(AppletProxyGenerator.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:257)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:96)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:173)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to build the dependencies that you're using (jar/war) with the same GWT SDK version that you are using for compilation of your project i.e. if 2.4 then use 2.4 to jar the dependencies and then compile your project. This error is due to the mismatch in the SDK versions being used.

Answer (score 0):

There have been breaking changes in the GWT code generator feature, between version 1.7 and 2.0. So make sure you have the current version of GwtAI, if you work with a GWT version 2.0 or higher. If you work with a GWT version before 2.0 go to the [GwtAI download page](http://code.google.com/p/gwtai/downloads/list), select *All downloads* and click *Search*, you should see GwtAI 0.2 files. Those
should work with older GWT versions.